# What is the use of images in config.json in stencil bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

What is the use of `images:{}` inside variations in config.json in stencil bigcommerce?

Comment: It is no longer used. The info originally stored here was moved into settings.

Comment: Thanks,could you please help me to identify how to import different images based on different  variations in our theme